# Human modified by 3 different alien species to save Earth from an alien threat

Tags: story-identification

I read this prior to 1982, hardback, at my High School Library. The story evolves as a Man is changed further away from humanity and his growing feeling of isolation. After he completed the 3 major modifications he is no longer considered Human. He meets the Unknown Entity and they recognize that each is alone and they leave together, no longer alone and the Earth is safe